# How to be sure Cortana is not present in a Windows 10 rollback

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, cortana

I'm interested in ensuring some of the datamining bits (Cortana, etc..) are fully removed. Where should I look / how can I verify that when I rolled back to 7 pro 64bit, these features were actually removed. Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you upgraded to Windows 10, your Windows 7 installation was moved not removed, when you rolled back, your Windows 10 installation was removed and the Windows 7 installation was moved back to its original location.  Windows 7 has zero Cortana functionality, it wouldn't be possible, for any of its services to exist in Windows 7.  This question appears to be basic fear mongering on unproven rumors from paranoid.people.

Comment: There's no fearmongering beyond what you're reading into it. It's a simple question - "I want to make sure application x has gone. Where does it keep its files?" The question is entirely reasonable, +1.

Comment: @RJFalconer - All Windows 10 components were removed when you restored Windows 8.

Comment: ...which is all you needed to say. (I'm not the OP btw).

Comment: @RJFalconer Not sure I agree its a reasonable question; have new features of Windows ever been left when reverting back?  I've not heard of that ever happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, most of the Cortana files are located in `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps`, and there are a few `Cortana.dll` files in `C:\Windows\System32`. Each .dll has Cortana in the name, so just search for Cortana.dll. Don't forget to put an asterisk(*) before and after Cortana so it uses a wildcard search.

**Note on Windows.old Folder** after upgrading to Windows 10, your old files that are related to your previous OS are stored in the folder `Windows.old`. However, Windows 10 will automatically delete this folder 30 days after you upgraded. So it may be wise to back up that folder on an external device or presumably away from the default location `C:\Windows.old`. I'm not 100% sure if it scans the whole hard drive for Windows.old or just that default location.

Answer (score 0):

You can try opening up your file folder and selecting "This P.C".

[image]

Then in the far right upper margin there is a search box
with a small magnifying glass.

[image]
In that box type the word "Everywhere."

You will see a 1kb file folder labeled "Everywhere" with a the file type labeled "Saved Searches"

[image]

Select that folder. This will do a full search of all folders and files and pull up ones that were moved. Even the moved after a factory restore.

Organizing them by "name" and will help to look them but there will be a lot of files and folders to look through.

Comment: Did you perhaps answer the wrong question?